Ubuntu 22.04 stuck in emergency mode
I force reboot my laptop after a fail in the installation of a printer. I remember before rebooting that I used stacer to clean the cache, logs, and removed some snapd packages using it also.
Now my system is stuck into an emergency mode.
I took a photo of the boot messages before going into that emergency mode. Here's a link.


Does this answer your question? What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ..."

I tried it earlier but when I try to run the fsck -f on nvme1n1p2 where mountpoints / is located. It says can't continue is mounted. @OrganicMarble

Like the other answer said, you need to boot your system to a live USB so you can run the check.

Tried it with a live USB and it didn't work @OrganicMarble

What does that mean "didn't work"? You didn't have disk problems, or it didn't fix them? If you want help, give specifics.

Well I have two nvme disks one is for windows and the other is for Linux. The one with Linux nvme1n1 shows two partitions. The one containing files and system is clean and doesn't have any issues when I run fsck on it. Meanwhile the one labeled ESP shows a super-block problem and it is labeled ESP. Practically it should be the one that controls the EFI. But both fsck and e2fsck don't work on it when I try to fix it @OrganicMarble

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
